# How to know google map controls creation is done?

Tags: google-maps

I need to dynamically create a ui widget with a parent div.id='myDivId', which is a google map control.

```
var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);

centerControlDiv.index = 1;
centerControlDiv.id = 'myDivId';
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);

// $('#myDivId') causes exception as $('#myDivId') is not created on 
// map as a DOM element yet.

var uiWidget = new uiWidget('myDivId');

// $(#myDivId) is used in class uiWidget().

class uiWidget {
  constructor(divId) {

    this.id = divId;

    // It should fail here due to this.$div property, as 
    // div 'myDivId' is not a DOM element yet by google map 
    // controls API.
    this.$div.click($.proxy(this.event_click, this));
  }


  get $div() {
    return $(‘#’ + this.id);
  }

  event_click(eve) {

  }
}
```

But, there is no event of when this parent div is created. Therefore, the child ui widget can't be created at correct time.

How to know parent div with id 'myDivId' is created?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference a DOM element by ID as a child of `document` when that element has only been created but not yet added to the `document`.

But you already have a reference to the `#myDivId` element in the `centerControlDiv` variable, so you don't need to use the ID to reference it. Just change this line:

`$('#myDivId').append("<div>UI widget</div>");`

to:

`$(centerControlDiv).append("<div>UI widget</div>");`

Put another way, to answer your question "How to know parent div with id 'myDivId' is created?", that div already is *created* - you created it in the `document.createElement('div')` call. It just isn't a child of `document` yet.

So when you use `$('#myDivId')`, or similar calls like `document.getElementById('myDivId')`, those calls can't see it. It's just a standalone element that you have a reference to, so you can access it through that element instead of looking it up in the document DOM.

Update based on your latest code:

To apply this principle to your `uiWidget` class, you can have the class work with the actual `div` element you created instead of accessing it by ID. Even better, since you're using jQuery, pass it a jQuery object from the beginning, like this:

```
var uiWidget = new UiWidget( $(centerControlDiv) );

class UiWidget {
  constructor($div) {
    this.$div = $div;
    this.$div.click($.proxy(this.event_click, this));
  }

  // ...
}
```

As you can see, the code no longer requires the div ID at all, and it doesn't need the `get $div()` either. `$div` and `this.$div` are already a jQuery object wrapping your `centerControlDiv`.

I also changed the name of the class to `UiWidget` to follow recommended JavaScript style and avoid conflict with the `uiWidget` variable that holds an instance of the class.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for answering the question. I have no problem with the script from google doc. I added more to my original question so that it's more clear what my issue is.

Comment: You solution should work with simple html, but I need to use $('#myDivId).append("<div>UI widget</div>"). The reason is that I need to create a "UI widget". It is a ES6 class which uses Jquery to create handlers for html selector in the component. Your solution does not work, as JQuery does not work. google map controls created event handler is the only solution as far as I know.

Comment: If you can post the source code for the `uiWidget()` function that you are calling in the latest update to your question, or a documentation page for it, we might be able to figure something out. Otherwise I can only make guesses as to what that function does and what argument(s) it expects, and my guesses are likely to be wrong. :-)

Comment: Thank you Michael, I added a sample class.